# Is there a way to separate downloaded videos and camera videos?

Tags: external-sd, video

So I recently got a Galaxy S4 and switched from Apple to Android. I like to download music videos to watch offline but when I moved the videos onto my phone, I found out that the music videos are stored in the same location as where the camera roll saves videos. On Apple you there was a built in app that could store videos while videos recorded by the camera could be stored on the camera roll. Is there a way to do this on Android? I used my micro SD card to move the videos to my phone by creating a new folder on the SD card named VIDEOS.

Comment: Are you using the default gallery to access the videos? Default might be doing this. I use [Piktures](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.diune.pictures&hl=en) gallery app which allows you to see camera and other videos separately, not to mention the GUI seems much nicer than the default one (I don't have S4 but it shouldn't matter). Anyhow, if you only intend to watch videos, then why not use a powerful multimedia player like [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en)? It keeps the videos separated and does the job well.

Comment: When you go to the gallery you should be able to see a Folder named VIDEOS under which you can see all your videos listed..

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you just need to sort the view in your default gallery app. Try sorting videos album vise and your problem will be over.

Answer (score -1):

Try Redirect Pro, 
It's a file organizer with some really cool features. 
[Link to Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailshttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tobino.redirectsfree)

Comment: While this might be a valid answer, it definitely needs some improvement. Could you please [edit] it and 1) include a link to the product and 2) a few more details on what it is and what it does? Thanks in advance!